# Caching Codeigniter's pagination with results

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

I have a search form that would search my database, I cache the results with the current options selected and the query for a key to identify the cached item, e.g.

```
md5([query]:[search-options]:[page-number]);
```

Since I cache with the Codeigniter's caching library, when search results are cached, I store them under the key for example:

```
United States:match=yes|rooms=5|order=date|type=desc|include-pictures=true:5
```

So this refers as searching for `United states` with the chosen options and page 5. This can change to anything like this:

```
United States:match=no|include-pictures=false:2
Washington, United States:match=no|include-pictures=false:2
```

Now this is a problem, when a record is updated, it doesn't reflect the search results until the cache has expired, what would be the best practise to cache results and updated records would reflect those results (that are cached)?

Answer (score 1):

> Now this is a problem, when a record is updated, it doesn't reflect the search results until the cache has expired

Maybe I'm missing something, but generally that's how you want the cache to work. You cache the results, use them to present data, and the cache is periodically refreshed once it expires.

If you need the cache up-to-date at all times, you can explicitly delete it when a record is updated. Just wipe the entire search result cache when something is updated.

If the problem is that your pagination is out of sync, make sure you're reading the pagination data from cache as well.

---

#### Deleteing only cache files that belong to a certain "group"

This is easy enough to do in theory: Write the cache files to their own directory (most likely within the default cache directory). When you need to delete the cache that belongs to this "group", just delete the directory or it's contents.

The problem is that Codeigniter's current [cache drivers](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html) have no support for this functionality, although it would be easy to integrate. In the meantime, you could write your own driver, but you might want to also overload the `CI_Cache` library itself, as the interface it provides for the drivers isn't very robust. For instance, the `save()` method currently look like this:

```
/**
 * Cache Save
 *
 * @param   string      Unique Key
 * @param   mixed       Data to store
 * @param   int         Length of time (in seconds) to cache the data
 *
 * @return  boolean     true on success/false on failure
 */
public function save($id, $data, $ttl = 60)
{
    return $this->{$this->_adapter}->save($id, $data, $ttl);
}
```

With only `$id, $data, $ttl` to work with, you'd have to do something like pass an array to one of the parameters in your custom adapter. Something like:

```
$cache_data = array(
    'group' => 'search_results', // Save to this cache directory
    'id' => $my_id,              // Standard params
    'ttl' => $my_ttl,
    'data' => $my_dat,
);
$this->cache->save($cache_data);
```

However, this breaks when using other adapters, and so does overloading the `CI_Cache` class to change the interface.

I know this isn't handing you the answer, but I did look at this and wanted to share my results. You might want to roll your own custom solution, alter an existing solution, or just let the cache expire and refresh according to your `$ttl` rather than have to rebuild it after every database update.

Definitely consider [Nico Kang's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9506322/398242) of kepping track of the individual cache `$id`s so you can skip the mess I've detailed above and explicitly delete the cache files you need to update.

Comment: `Just wipe the entire search result cache when something is updated.` That's one of the main issues, when hashing the query, options and the page number, it returns different hashes that will be difficult to delete cached results that has relevant information that are cached when it needs to be updated.

Comment: Wait, what exactly are you caching? HTML output or database results?

Comment: Because that's how the options go into when options are stored, it changes the SQL syntax e.g. `order=date` would do `ORDER BY date`, etc. The page number would change the limit offset, e.g. `LIMIT $page_number, 25`.

Comment: I realized afterwards those things are significant and deleted my last comment, my mistake. I still don't understand why you can't clear the cache on update? Just to be clear, let's see the actual code you use to manage and create the cache files. I'm not entirely sure which cache library/driver/methods you're using.

Comment: Okay. The search results are cached. When editing a record from the results, it'll take you to a page to update the record, when it's submitted and updated in the database - it doesn't reflect the search results when you are submitting the **same** options, query and page number it will still show the old *non-updated* record in the cached result since it hasn't expired BUT when it's expired, it shows the new updated record in the results - that way I cannot determine HOW the user searched and got the record when the hashed cache key is ambigious.

Comment: I'm using Codeigniter's file caching.

Comment: I see, I've been using [Phil Sturgeon's cache library](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-cache) for the past few years, I didn't realize CI has a better native cache system now. So there's no way to sort of "namespace" these particular cache files so they can be deleted all at once without touching unrelated objects? If there was, does that sound like it would be in the general direction of what you want?

Comment: Sadly, no. Namespace caching would be great in PHP or a wildcard cache system.

Comment: What I'm asking is: Would having a way to delete *all* the "search" cache be a satisfactory resolution to your problem? If so, I can probably give you a solution tomorrow (heading out for tonight).

Comment: Hmm, but I don't see how that can be possible? But sure, I'll check back with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

With search the only real solution is to clear the cache once you updated a row.
Caching search results that need to be up-to-date brings the problem that 1 row can exist in an unlimited amount of caching keys.

What you can do to keep at least some parts of the cache, is to only delete cached items that are linked to the search.
for example you can start all cache that is created from the search with SEARCH:
And when you update a row, you just loop through the whole cache, and delete the ones starting with SEARCH:

There are some other possibilities, like keeping a list with all cached search items, if it's not in there, create it, and if it is in there, use it.
And every time you update a row, you just clean this cache item, and start with an empty array again.
This will save you some trouble with looping through a list with all the cached items, but it will make a tiny bit of extra load every time you want to request the cache.